# how can i downgrade from 12.04.3 kernel and it's xservers to 12.04.2 ones?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, downgrade, xserver

Hi how can i get back (downgrade) from 12.04.3 kernel and it's xservers to 12.04.2 ones? i have [some problems with 12.04.3 kernel](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2173442) and want to downgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remove raring kernel and X stack by running the following command

`sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring`

> NOTE: Do not install the `linux-current-generic` package as it will install the latest release kernel (now it's raring's 3.8).

This should roll back to 12.04.2. If NOT, manually install quantal kernel and x stacks manually => `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal`.

Refer to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get downgrade the Kernels then you can get those old kernels from here

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/testing/index.html

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

those are having kernels and from there you can get them & install.